# PUT request in Chrome Extension using Google API not rendering

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-sheets-api

I'm stuck at this point of my code wherein I have successfully called the Sheets API using PUT request, but it's not rendering on the Google Sheet.

Here is my code where I use both PUT and GET requests to see if the data changed:

background.js

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true }, getToken);

function getToken(token) {

console.log('this is the token: ', token);

  var params = {
    "range":"Sheet1!A1:B1",
    "majorDimension": "ROWS",
      "values": [
      ["Hi","Crush"]
    ],
  }
  let init = {
    method: 'PUT',
    async: true,
    data: params,
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    'contentType': 'json',
  };
  fetch(
      "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1efS6aMlPFqHJJdG8tQw-BNlv9WbA21jQlufsgtMsUmw/values/Sheet1!A1:B1?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED",
      init)
      .then((response) => console.log(response))

      let request = {
        method: 'GET',
        async: true,
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        'contentType': 'json',
      };
      fetch(
          "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1efS6aMlPFqHJJdG8tQw-BNlv9WbA21jQlufsgtMsUmw/values/Sheet1!A1:B1",
          request)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then(function(data) {
            console.log(data)
          });
}
```

Here's the screenshot of my Google Sheet, the data didn't change. The status of the PUT request is 200 and it seems the data is still **Hello World** in `A1:B1`:

[image]

Here's the log:

[image]

Do you have any idea what's missing here?

Comment: I think that your request body for Sheets API is correct. So although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution, how about this modification? When ``data: params,`` is modified to ``data: JSON.stringify(params),``, what result will you get? By the way, what is ``'contentType': 'json',`` in ``request``?

Comment: @Tanaike, I have tried to modify my code to `data: JSON.stringify(params)` and the text still didn't change. I have removed the 'contentType': 'json' in the request.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize my comment was not useful for your situation.

Comment: It's okay, I'm still figuring out why the request is not rendering on the cells.

Comment: When I could replicate your situation and completely resolve your issue, I would like to comment here.

Comment: That will be a great help! Thanks :)

Comment: I proposed a modification point. Could you please confirm it? In my environment, I could replicate your situation and confirm that the script worked by this modification. But if this was not the solution of your issue, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification? Please modify the object of `init` as follows.

#### From:

```
data: params,
```

#### To:

```
body: JSON.stringify(params),
```

#### Reference:

- [Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: It works! I also tried this one from my previous code and it returns 400 Bad request and I thought there's something wrong. Thank you so much!

Comment: @jess Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.